# Generate unique id or class for the canvas tag eveytime a question is asked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I just wanted to know is there any chance I can dynamically generate a random id for my canvas in js/HTML?
I am appending a screenshot of my current work done until now.[Current work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV9jn.png)

In this image, there is a container in which a chart is rendering also there a expand button on the top left which takes to a modal where a zoom image of the same chart shows.

My main concern is, for the first question it shows properly but when I ask second question it is not showing the chart in the second question's container. I think it is getting the same id which is why it is doing it so. I just wanted some references where I can generate new id every time a question is asked?
Is it Possible?? I am a newbie to frontend coding a help would be great

Comment: There are npm  modules such as 'uuid' and 'uuidv4' you can try. If you can't import these modules, you can go to their github to get the source code and copy that to your project. Remember to look at the LICENSE though,.

Answer (score 0):

You could try generating a random number for the id. If you're getting your questions from an array of objects, just loop through them & set the id to the random number. Something like this should work

```
  for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  myArr[i].id = Math.random() * (1000 - 50) + 50;
}
```